# Svelte - Trying to access a 'readable' object within 'store.js' returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, svelte

As you can see in the image below, you can access a normal `Object` (which is to be expected) but not a `readable` one inside `stores.js`.

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
    import { myStuff, myStuff2 } from './stores.js';
</script>

<h1>This is {$myStuff.TEST}</h1>
<h1>This is {myStuff2.TEST}</h1>
```

**stores.js**

```
import { readable } from 'svelte/store';

export const myStuff = readable({
    TEST: "HELLO"
});

export const myStuff2 = {
    TEST: "HELLO 2"
};

// Doesn't work
console.log("TEST FROM STORE: " + myStuff.TEST);

// Works
console.log("TEST FROM STORE: " + myStuff2.TEST);
```

[image: script_result]

Why does this happen?

The [Tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/readable-stores) mentions briefly that you might get an `undefiend` but it doesn't elaborate much past that and the [Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-readable) don't mention that possible outcome as of writing this.

Screenshot of the example from the marked answer:

[image: use_within_storejs_example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way stores work in Svelte is that they wrap your value in a class which doesn't have a direct way to get the stored value. You would need to subscribe to it to get it. There's also a [`get`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-get) method which does the same under the hood.

So in your code this would print the value. It will also print the new values as it changes.

```
const unsub=mystuff.subscribe(val=> console.log("CURRENT VALUE OF TEST FROM STORE: " + val.TEST))
unsub()

//this does the same thing:
import { get } from 'svelte/store';
console.log("TEST FROM STORE: " + get(myStuff).TEST);
```

In the .svelte files the $____ notation does this subscription for you to make it more convenient to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-get):

> Generally, you should read the value of a store by subscribing to it
> and using the value as it changes over time. Occasionally, you may
> need to retrieve the value of a store to which you're not subscribed.
> get allows you to do so.

For example:

```
import { readable, get } from 'svelte/store';

console.log("TEST FROM STORE: " + get(myStuff).TEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [origin svelte docs about readable store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-readable)
2. when you create **readable** store, this store return { **subscriber** }
3. **$store.field** - use only in svelte component
4. if you want to log your values:

```js
import { readable, get } from 'svelte/store';
// to get fields in your store
console.log("keys in your store" + Object.keys(myStuff));
// to get value
console.log("get value from your store" + get(myStuff).TEST);
```